# Android Vector Drawable crash

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I use Vector Drawables. It works good on my several devices, but on my Sony with Android 5.0.2 I get at my application launch:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=32; index=32
 at android.util.PathParser$PathDataNode.addCommand(PathParser.java:370)
 at android.util.PathParser$PathDataNode.nodesToPath(PathParser.java:260)
 at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VPath.toPath(VectorDrawable.java:1265)
  at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VPathRenderer.drawPath(VectorDrawable.java:950)
```

Looks like I have some svgs converted to xml with unsupported tags for this device. But how to understand which ones and how to be sure that it will work on all other supported devices.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The same problem http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78162 (**Closed: Oct 2014**) Problem was that one of my vector xml contained a [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

So at this moment to be sure that you application will work on all devices, make sure that your xml vector drawables don't contain **e-**

Answer (score 5):

This error may occur on Android 5.0.1
Reason: in the presence of vector image descriptor numbers in scientific format (scientific notation), for example, 8.8e-5

Look for the following entry in the tag  your vector images in the project

**Solution**: The decision to alter those numbers in the format without the exhibitors in this case will be the result, 0.000088

Comment: You save my day

Answer (score 1):

In my xml were present `<group></group>` attributes.

[image]

After their removing problem was solved, also spent some time to understand where was the problem, and it was not by M and L letters (read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after passing my svg through the [Android SVG to VectorDrawable](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/). Turned out some of the paths it generated had the letter 'L' right after the first number. Removing it remedied the error.

Answer (score -3):

Searching for a solution I found some workarounds like switch the OS language to English.

You can read more in the issue tracker [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193832) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194512).

Comment: The bugs reports you linked to are for Android Studio itself. The question was about the app crashing at runtime.